# How to append a new tag to an xml tree with BS4?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I was experimenting with BS4 since I'm trying to write a script to monitor a web API. So I made this simple xml file

```
<system>
   <load>0.03</load>
   <user>7.4</user>
   <system>3.2</system>
   <wait>0.9</wait>
</system>
```

what I want is to copy the first tag in "system" which is "load" and append it again to the end of the system tag. So I wrote this script in python

```
import bs4
with open("test.xml") as infile2:
    tree = bs4.BeautifulSoup(infile2.read(), "lxml")
    load_tag = tree.system.load
    tree.system.append(load_tag)`
```

but instead of copying the load tag to the end it actually moved it
so instead of this

```
<system>
    <load>0.03</load>
    <user>7.4</user>
    <system>3.2</system>
    <wait>0.9</wait>
    <load>0.03</load>
</system>
```

I got this

```
<system>
    <user>7.4</user>
    <system>3.2</system>
    <wait>0.9</wait>
    <load>0.03</load>
</system>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `copy.copy`

**Ex:**

```
import bs4
from copy import copy

with open("test.xml") as infile2:
    tree = bs4.BeautifulSoup(infile2.read(), "lxml")
    load_tag = tree.system.load
    tree.system.append(copy(load_tag))
```

**Output:**

```
<system>
    <load>0.03</load>
    <user>7.4</user>
    <system>3.2</system>
    <wait>0.9</wait>
    <load>0.03</load>
</system>
```